# What is the ASP.NET account in Windows 7?

Tags: asp.net, windows-7

In Windows XP, when we installed ASP.NET, we got a default user called ASPNET. I used to give permissions to this user in the database, since ASP.NET applications ran under this user context.

What is the corresponding account in Windows 7? Does it get automatically created when .NET is installed?

Answer (score 1):

Since IIS 6, w3wp.exe hosts ASP.NET applications and this worker process by default uses Network Service account instead. 
create a normal user account and grant specific rights to do these things.Or from the application you can impersonate a user to give specific rights.